# Problem with size of custom MFC control when Language is set to Japanese

Tags: mfc, cjk

I look after the DeepSkyStacker application.

If the system language is set to English, then DeepSkyStacker sets its own language to English, and its "Processing" panel (on the right) is displayed correctly:

[image: English]

If the system language is set to Japanese, then DeepSkyStacker sets its own language to English as there's no Japanese translation done, its "Processing" panel is then displayed incorrectly:

[image: Japanese]

Specifically the "Gradient" slider controls are displayed with a height of 51 pixels whereas when the language is set to English they are only 46 pixels high:

[image: English Gradient control]

Has anyone got any idea what could cause this?

The dialog definition reads:

```
IDD_RGB DIALOGEX 0, 0, 164, 126
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "RGB/K Levels"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg 2", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "Gradient",IDC_REDGRADIENT,"MFCGradientCtrl",WS_TABSTOP,16,3,148,30,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CONTROL         "Gradient",IDC_GREENGRADIENT,"MFCGradientCtrl",WS_TABSTOP,16,35,148,30,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CONTROL         "Gradient",IDC_BLUEGRADIENT,"MFCGradientCtrl",WS_TABSTOP,16,67,148,30,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Reset",IDC_RESET,116,112,48,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Apply",IDC_PROCESS,0,112,48,14
    CONTROL         "Linked settings",IDC_LINK,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,3,100,63,10
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_UNDO,57,112,16,12
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_REDO,95,112,16,12
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_SETTINGS,76,112,16,12
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_RED_HAT,2,5,14,27
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_GREEN_HAT,2,37,14,27
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_BLUE_HAT,2,69,14,27
END
```

David

Comment: Possibly using the wrong/unintended font fallback for DLU calculations (see [What other effects does DS_SHELLFONT have on property sheet pages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050208-00/?p=36503)).

Comment: All my dialogs are set to use `FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0`.

Comment: Just to verify that the font (and DLU calculations) are actually part of the problem, have the program call [`MapDialogRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapdialogrect) in either setup and output the results. If they are different, the issue is probably related to the dialog's font.

Comment: So if I have just called (e.g.) CPropertySheet::AddPage(&rgbTab) where RGBTab is a CChildPropertyPage subclass that creates the dlg by passing the IDD to the CChildPropertyPage ctor.  How do I code that?   I don't think my code can know the size of the dlg in DLUs at that point.  Or the size of the contained controls which are having the problem...

Guidance welcome

Comment: The comment wasn't meant as part of a solution rather than getting closer to figuring out what's going wrong. It was suggesting to pass an *arbitrary* `RECT` (such as `RECT { 0, 0, 1, 1 };`) into `MapDialogRect` and comparing the returned `RECT` under either system setting. As for guidance: Don't go Qt if you care about UI quality.

Comment: Aha - that I can do easily.  Thanks

Comment: English:
Crect before  { 0 ,  0 ,  100 ,  100 }
Crect after   { 0 ,  0 ,  200 ,  200 }

Japanese:

Crect before  { 0 ,  0 ,  100 ,  100 }
Crect after   { 0 ,  0 ,  200 ,  250 }
I see a smoking gun!

Comment: The dialog unit to pixel conversion is based on your system font, not necessarily the one you've selected into the dialog.

Comment: Perhaps so, but how to stop those controls being oversized so that half the dlg is clipped.

Comment: I understand the issue of the scaling of the control sizes within the dlg based on the default font for the language.  What I don't "get" is that IMHO that same scaling should have been applied to the entire dlg but it appears that the height of the dialog doesn't get scaled even though the height and positions of the contained controls were scaled vertically by a factor of 5/4

Comment: I tried changing the font to: FONT 8, "Tahoma", 0, 0, 0x1 but that didn't change the behaviour :(

Comment: That's puzzling indeed. One would naïvely assume that `"Tahoma"` (or any other font, for that matter) would be the same regardless of circumstantial system settings. I don't have an answer to that riddle, just an idea on how to drill deeper: Send a [`WM_GETFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getfont) message to the dialog, and inspect the [`LOGFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfontw) returned by a subsequent call to [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by creating a resource file specifically for Japanese which was copied from the English one, and then edited the dialog definitions for the controls that were clipped so that the clipping didn't happen any more (I reduced height of most controls by a factor of 1.25 and moved them up as necessary).

David